# Good way of trimming a glass plate?

Tags: glass, cutting

I have a cooker hood in mind which has a flat glass plate around the chimney/suction part, just short of 1cm thick. (I want this particular design as the hood will obscure a window slightly and also so I can store light things such as salt, pepper and a few herbs/spices on top of it.)

It is wider than the hob and it may make sense to trim it a bit on one side to allow for a better/deeper cupboard. What is a good way to do this?

The first tool at home I think of is an angle grinder... but I have never used it with glass and I don't know anybody who has. (And I have a lot of respect for these after using them on tiles or metal, even if, say, I was wearing glass splinter resistant head and limb protection!) Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to modify an existing glass component, or how to manufacture your own?

Comment: There's every likelihood an existing hood uses tempered glass, which is effectively un-cuttable. Can you link to the one you have in mind?

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to modify it. [This sort of design](http://www.maan-cooker-hoods.co.uk/chimney_cooker_hoods/maan_chimney_cooker_hood_lazur_fit.html).

Answer (score 2):

Although I couldn't find specific reference to tempered glass on the model you listed, other Maan hoods do refer to having tempered glass. The final authority on this would be the manufacturer.

Unfortunately, you can't cut or drill tempered glass. (Essentially, the glass has been treated such that it breaks into small and hopefully less lethal bits when it's broken.)